# SocketIO with Temp Sensor - I almost done DS18B20 on my Raspberry Pi with NodeJS and SocketIO, how can I extract Promise { data }?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I connect DS18B20 to Raspberry Pi and I try to use NodeJS with React to display the temperature on the browser, I also use SocketIO to display realtime temperature because the temperature always changes.

I have temperature.js to get the temperature from file, this is ok.

I have app.js as the server with socketio, I try to call function but it show Promise { pending } , then I change to async/await, now I can get the temperature but on the client side is error.

app.js as below

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const port = 4001;
const index = require('./routes/index');

const getTemperature = require('./utils/temperature');

const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIO(server);

let interval;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  if(interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

async function broadcast() {
  var temp = await getTemperature();
  return temp;
}
var temperature = broadcast();

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
  const response = temperature;
  console.log(response);
  socket.emit("FromAPI", response);
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

The error from the client side = "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})"

Below is the console.log result

```
Promise { 29.062 }
Promise { 29.062 }
Promise { 29.062 }
Promise { 29.062 }
```

How can I get the data from the Promise { data }???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try this:

---

`broadcast().then(t => { console.log(t); });`

Comment: Thanks @ta4h1r
I get it right but from the console.log(response); show Promise { undefined }

Comment: Then you could change what is being returned in the broadcast() function. Try like this:

function broadcast() {
 return new Promise (async (resolve) => {
  temp = await getTemperature();
  resolve(temp);
 });
}

broadcast.then(t => {console.log(t);})

Comment: if I don't need console.log(t), what is the syntax? Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I get this error from client -> "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: You need to do your socket.emit from a location where you have the resolved promise value. I would say the easiest way to do it is to return a new promise that resolves to the required temperature value within your getTemperature() function.